# I am not able to reach login screen

Tags: login-screen, tty, bleachbit

I was using bleachbit
then the system got stuck
It was not working
I did a force shutdown
Now when I reboot I am not able to reach the login screen
I entered the tty and found that the system had no space left.
Please help me out, I have a lot of important files in it all in the root partition

Comment: If there is insufficient space in $HOME (your user directory), a GUI login won't be necessary. The fix is to either expand the partition (recommended minimum is 25GB for /, is that what you have?) or to delete files/programs until you have sufficient space. You've provided limited details for us to help currently.  What did you mean by force-shutdown?  A SysRq key combination to cleanly reboot or something else?

Comment: thanks, i pressed the power button for 7 seconds to forcefully shutdown the system

Comment: can you help me with the commandline to do so

Comment: i would always cleanly shutdown your system (ie. using keyboard commands to tell system to power off, reboot etc via SysRq commands), however if power went out (or power-button was pressed), I'd not reboot until I'd have `fsck` (file system checked) your system to ensure any damage done via unclean shutdown was fixed..  I'd recommend you `fsck` your system from a *live* system (such as Ubuntu install media, so your hdd/ssd isn't in use and `fsck` is easy to perform)

Comment: the tty is showing 'cannot create temporary file in /tmp/ no space left on device' when i run neofetch

Comment: i just have to type fsck in the tty

Comment: You can also use a live USB stick to temporarily move your unnecessary files away from the full partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, boot from a CD, USB, or network in recovery mode or live mode.

Second, delete the large files in `~/.cache/` as suggested in the [BleachBit FAQ](https://docs.bleachbit.org/doc/frequently-asked-questions.html) entry "Q: I closed BleachBit while it was working for a long time, and now my hard drive is full. How do I fix it?". It is often safe to delete the whole `~/.cache/` folder.